# Are there known issues with Android Services on 4.1.x (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: android, android-4.1-jelly-bean

**My question** is a shot in the dark: what is the deal with Android 4.x / Jelly Bean? Are there known problems with services, stickiness, foreground, etc.?

**Backstory**: I tested my music player application successfully on all sorts of Android devices and emulators and then just recently on a physical Jelly Bean device (Samsung Rugby Pro). I found that the `MediaPlayer` `onCompletion` function is *not* being fired consistently when the screen is turned off. Most often it isn't fired for *several minutes*. When the screen is on, whether or not my activity is shown, the application works just fine.

*(There are no problems on Gingerbread, KitKat, Lollipop, or Marshmallow. I have physical devices for those versions and they all work flawlessly.)*

Device Information:

- OS VERSION: 3.0.31-656355
- RELEASE: 4.1.1
- DEVICE: comancheatt
- MODEL: SAMSUNG-SGH-I547
- PRODUCT: comancheuc
- BRAND: samsung
- DISPLAY: JRO03L.I547UCBLL1
- CPU_ABI: armeabi-v7a
- CPU_ABI2: armeabi
- HARDWARE: qcom
- ID: JRO03L
- MANUFACTURER: samsung
- USER: se.infra
- HOST: SEP-125

Comment: Is this a bound service or started service?

Comment: The service is started and bound to in the activity's `onResume` and then unbound in `onPause`. If the service isn't being used then in `onPause` it is also stopped.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Yes, thanks for the obvious of which I've read. The service is *still running*. I'm going to guess like most of the difficult questions on SO, this one won't be answered until I figure it out myself :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out; I hope this helps you too ...

The problem is *not* in firing the `onCompletion` event but rather that `reset()` blocks indefinitely. I had previously attributed this to [Android issue #959: MediaPlayer "crash" (deadlocks the calling thread) when resetting or releasing an unused MediaPlayer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=959) which was incorrect for my case.

My particular problem was aggressive sleep behavior on my test device. This bug would pop up when I ran in Airplane Mode with few other apps because the call to `reset()` (or `release()`) also releases the `MediaPlayer` instance's `WakeLock`. Once that occurred the device would sleep and the code would appear to block in that function. I was unable to reproduce this with a debugger attached and/or plugged in because either of those prevented the device from sleeping!

**My solution** was to create a separately managed `WakeLock` which I `acquire()` basically when playback begins and `release()` after all songs have played through. Technically, I do this only when the activity has been paused and also release on resume because it's unnecessary to hold a `WakeLock` when the device is awake already.

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```